# After the while True loop, an error about syntaxerror was found

Tags: while-loop

- I was writing the code that was inside the while loop but I got syntaxError.
- 

my codes are=

```
number = 0
even = 0
odd = 0
while True = 
    number = input('add ra vared kned\n> ')
    if number == 'end' or number == 'finish' or number == 'done' :
        break
    number = int(number)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even = even + 1
    else :
        odd = odd + 1

print ('Number of even numbers =',even, 'Number of odd numbers =',odd )
```

This program is about calculating even and odd numbers written by while and an error appears after while True code.
the rest of the codes are right.
help me

Comment: Please, tag the programming language!

Comment: I have fixed your code, hope it will work now.